# In what directory(s) are the default ubuntu icons located?

Tags: icons, default

I accidentally deleted the Downloads bookmark, and I wanted to recreate it with the same icon, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Icons are located in `/usr/share/icons`

Answer (score 19):

More specifically, the default icons that the file browser is using (currently up to version 15.04) are placed in folder:

```
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/48
```

The icon for the download folder is `folder-download.svg`.

Answer (score 9):

"Icons are located in `/usr/share/icons`"

This answer is only partially correct.  If one does a locate `*.png` on the command line,
many locations for icons will be found. For example, `/usr/share/unity/icons`,

```
/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/assets/switch-button-off.png
```

So a more generalized answer would be... in various directories under `/usr/share`

I don't know what a "downloads bookmark" is, so I can't address your specific issue any further.

Answer (score 2):

The default icons are placed in

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor
```

256x256 icons for example

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps
```

Anyway you can also replace this icons by pasting the wanted icon at the current theme folder