# Is there a good folder icon for "Programming" I can use in Ubuntu?

Tags: themes, icons

If you install ubuntu, you have unique folder icons for Documents, Music, Desktop, Downloads, etc etc. When I install Ubuntu, the first thing I do is to create an additional folder called "Programming", where I keep my project sources.

Is there a folder icon available for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look through the different icons for you theme: [In what directory(s) are the default ubuntu icons located?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132406/in-what-directorys-are-the-default-ubuntu-icons-located)  Mostly located in `/usr/share/icons`

There are a few ones that might work in `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/catagories/48`

[image]

[image]

Also, you can use any icon you want, Here is one I made custom that might work:

[image]

---

To use, right click on a folder -> Properties -> click on the folder picture -> select a replacement picture

[image]